# The WebSocket is in an invalid state ('Aborted') for this operation

Tags: c#, .net-core, microservices, ocelot

We're using subscriptions and we're seeing an unhandled exception in our log files with the following stack trace:

previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Exception caught in global error handler, exception message: The WebSocket is in an invalid state ('Aborted') for this operation. Valid states are: 'Open, CloseReceived', exception stack:    at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketValidate.ThrowIfInvalidState(WebSocketState currentState, Boolean isDisposed, WebSocketState[] validStates)

Comment: Your question contains no question.

Comment: Use from cmd.exe the following >Netstat -a to check state.  You probably have a Time Wait which indicates that you closed a previous connection from both ends at same time.